# Tag synonym request: vmware-player to vmware-workstation-player

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

Someone asked [a question that was explicitly about VMware Workstation Player](https://superuser.com/questions/1331144/vmware-workstation-player-14-cannot-seem-to-hide-top-bar).  They tagged it with the `vmware-workstation` tag, which has traditionally  been used for the product that is now known as VMware Workstation Pro.  Meanwhile, the product that has traditionally been known as VMware Player is now (confusingly) named VMware Workstation Player.  Someone even [answered the question providing a solution for the wrong product](https://superuser.com/a/1331158/210417), so clearly someone was confused by this.

VMware Workstation and VMware Workstation Pro are the same product and don't deserve separate tags.

VMware Player and VMware Workstation Player are the same product and don't deserve separate tags.

There currently is no separate `vmware-workstation-pro` tag (which is fine).  There is a separate `vmware-workstation-player` tag, which completely redundant. (And if anyone really thinks it's warranted, why not have separate tags for each product version then?)

(Aside: I made [a suggested edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/764358) to the aforementioned question, replacing the `vmware-workstation` tag with `vmware-player`, but it got rejected with:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

and

> The latest version is called VMWare Workstation Player. See https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation-player/workstation-player-evaluation.html

Sighhhhh.)

Comment: Ugh.  IMO you uncovered a bit of a mess.  FWIW (precisely zero) I agree with your assessment.